# How to open a file from active buffer into a split window?

Tags: vim-windows, split, multiple-files

I have some files in my vim buffer.

`:ls` shows the list of active buffer,
I want to open a file from buffer into a vertically/horizontally split window.

I know `:vsp` or `:sp` open split window in vim but how to open a split window from files in buffer?

Comment: Those are "buffers" (not "files") and they are in your "buffer list" (not "buffer").

Comment: But they represent files which have been recently opened. Right?

Comment: Related: see `:h gf` and `:h CTRL-W_f`.

Comment: No, they represent "documents" that may or may not be associated to actual files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can give

```
:vsplit | buffer buffernumber/buffername
```

to open a buffer in vertical split mode.

**Example:**

```
:split | buffer 3
```

Same applies to horizontal split mode too. You can use `:sp` as a shortcut for `:split` and `:vs` for `:vsplit`

Answer (score 7):

You can do `:2sbN` or `:sbN 2` to split the window and go to the 2 buffer. To split the window vertically, you can use `:vert sbN 3` to go to buffer 3.

An alternative solution is to use the `:sp [+cmd]` syntax. To vertical split the window and go to buffer 10 you would then use `:vsp +b10`.

Comment: It will be better if you could include the syntax for opening buffer through its name

Comment: the syntax is explained in the help

Comment: Why use `:sbN` over `:sb`? I fine `:sb` to be very hand as you can use partial filenames.

Comment: What is the meaning of `:sb` in understandable terms?

Comment: I think its split buffer.

Comment: @PeterRincker I understood the question as that the OP wanted to explicitly use buffer numbers. But looks like `:sb` would be possible as well..

Answer (score 3):

`:sp` and `:vs` take a filename as argument.

So you can do `:sp filename` and `:sp filename`.

The doc [`:h :sp`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:sp) says:

> :[N]sp[lit] [++opt] [+cmd] [file]
>
> If [file] is given it will be edited in the new window.  If it
>           is not loaded in any buffer, it will be read.  Else the new
>           window will use the already loaded buffer.